# как работает redirect() в django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Доброго времени суток, имеется следующая проблема:

При использовании `redirect()` пишет ошибку:

> NoReverseMatch at /owner/new/change
>   Reverse for 'order_status' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id_order': (1,)}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['owner/details']

views.py:

```
def order_manage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ManageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            id_order = form.cleaned_data['id_order']
        return redirect('order_status', {'id_order': id_order})
```

.....

```
def order_status(request):
    return render_to_response('app/owner/order_details_new.html')
```

Если убрать передачу переменной `({'id_order': id_order})` из  `order_manage()` - работает.

Пожалуйста, помогите с решением проблемы, и по возможности поясните принцип работы `redirect()` при передаче доп. переменных.

Answer (score 1):

Решил сам, проблема по причине того, что в url не была указана передаваемая переменная:
было так:

```
url(r'^owner/details', views.order_status, name = 'order_status'),
```

исправил, и заработало:

```
url(r'^owner/details/(?P<id_order>[0-9]+)/$', views.order_status, name = 'order_status'),
```